# Aws api gateway client module

Tags: node-modules

How will i pass a responseType value with *aws-gateway-client* module *invokeApi* function.Tried to pass it as  additional parameters,headers,pathparameters and all.

````
invokeUrl:Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
region:Xxxxxxxx,
accessKey:xXxxxxxxxxxx,
secretKey:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
});
var res= await apigClient.invokeApi(pathParamas,pathTemplate,method,additionalParams,data).then(function to handle response data).catch(error handling function)```
````